# Is there a better way to check to see if user X is a member of group Y in BASH on Linux without using getent?

Tags: bash

To clarify:

```
getent group | grep someGroup | grep someUser
```

Problem: This dumps the entire group db, which might be attached to LDAP, etc., in an enterprise environment, and then filters them with grep to see if the user is there in someGroup.

So that's all groups, everywhere. Ouch.

Furthermore, administrative commands are often set to something that makes them completely unusable for anyone but an administrator. Even for a simple "Hey, is he a member of that group?" type query.  Can't use the `if [ -f -d etc...]` commands because I'm doing it preparatory to a `sodu -u someUser` execution. This is to say that the script isn't running as the user in question.

Question: Is there a better way?

Comment: id someUser -g   or id someUser  will return the user's group for you without doing a grep...

Comment: OK, I'll choose one of the answers when I get to work on Monday.  To be frank, I didn't think anyone would have anything but it's great to have at least two good possibilities. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know both the username and group (as you appear to), you can use [`id`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/id) like so:

```
id -Gn username | grep '\bgroupname\b'
```

`id -Gn` will display all group names a user is a member of, then `grep` will return 0 if the group is present or 1 if not.  `\b` matches only on word boundaries, which keeps you from matching substrings of group names (e.g. `every` for `everyone`).

I believe `id` is available on all Unix and Unix-like systems.  It's certainly present and functions the same way on Linux, OS X, and OpenBSD.  However, `\b` does not work on the latter, since it is using BSD `grep` instead of GNU `grep`—alternative patterns are required.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `groups myUser` which prints the groups a user is in, and then see if the list has your desired group.

Comment: Of interest: the OS X manpage on `groups` says "The `groups` utility has been obsoleted by the `id(1)` utility, and is equivalent to `id -Gn [user]`." https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/groups.1.html

Comment: It doesn't look like Linux's man pages have a similar warning.  I'd expect both to continue to be available forever…